# CSS: How do I get rid of unintended space on top

Tags: css

See this pic:

http://twitpic.com/5k3uph

The CSS I use is:

```
#content_filter_items {
    display: none;
    background-color: #ccc;
    padding: 3px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    clear: both; }

#content_filter_items .filter_item {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: white;
    width: 200px;
    padding: 2px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -o-border-radius: 5px;
    -ms-border-radius: 5px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    height: 100px; }
```

Why is it that I have the extra space on top of the 2nd column?

Thanks
Eric

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where you have `display: inline-block`, you also need to set `vertical-align: top`.

See the "baseline" section here for an explanation:

http://blog.mozilla.com/webdev/2009/02/20/cross-browser-inline-block/

Comment: Thank you. That fixed the issue. And, thanks for the link! I will accept the answer as soon as I am allowed to. :)